# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'nodecontactform-master\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Tags: javascript, node.js

`app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('contact')  'Erorr Here'
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));`

Comment: const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 
const app = express();

// View engine setup 
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Please may you provide a clear problem statement and a [mcve]?

Comment: Also may you remove that comment and edit the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.